# Make button with drawable as background look "pressed" on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Good evening everyone!

Is there a way to make my buttons look pressed without having to design two times each button?(one for pressed state, another for not pressed). I've designed the buttons' shapes using http://angrytools.com/android/button/, and using these shapes as the background for the buttons. I've heard about ImageButton but it doesnt seem to apply here as I need the buttons to have text.

Example of one of my background shapes:

[image]

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This Code, set this XML file as background to a button.

**but_background.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#9df20901" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="#892379" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```